# Text mode at startup + startx?

Tags: display, gnome, console, x-server, text-mode

I'm trying to boot my Trisquel GNU/Linux distro directly from text mode, as I don't want to load the GUI if it's not necessary. I would like to work in tty1 until I type startx, which would start all the graphical stuff.

Is there a way to do it? I used to have Musix, and it worked fine, but it was a default config.

**INFO:**

Distro: Trisquel 7.0
GUI: GNOME 3.8.4

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to a GNU linux box at present, but its usually (except in recent ubuntu's) set in the /etc/inittab file.  There should be an entry that says "initdefault" which will be set to a value of 5.  You need this to be 3 (multi-user no GUI).

Be very careful changing this file - corrupting it will mean booting in recovery mode and putting it right.

Comment: There's no such file: Trisquel is modified Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disable gdm (or the Display Manager you are using). For example, if it's a distro with systemd:

```
# systemctl disable gdm
```

You may need to ensure that getty will be started on tty1 upon boot:

```
# systemctl enable getty@tty1
```

To start GNOME with startx, you can run the following command:

```
$ startx /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

Make sure you have the the (xorg-)xinit package installed.

However, you would probably need to have a ~/.xinitrc file to load the necessary script in /etc/X11/xinitrc.d/ so that the GNOME apps can work properly:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

exec gnome-session
```

You simply run:

```
$ startx
```

in this case.

P.S. I suppose Trisquel doesn't use systemd but upstart though. So you would need to check out the equivalence of those systemctl commands of upstart.